# unable to start the service in ubuntu - 16.04

Tags: 16.04, systemd, services

I am tyring to start the service in ubuntu system inside `/etc/systemd/system` folder using this command:

```
systemctl start xxx.service
```

and I am getting the below error:

[image]

Any leads will be appreciated.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/472950 for a good explanation of Status 203 and how you can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It was a permissions issue. I resolved it using:

```
chmod 755 xxxxx
```